# Access the next button event android

Tags: android, keycode

I don't know if it's very clear, but i'm trying to do something when the "next" (bottom right corner of the keyboard) is pressed, and i can't find its keycode. 
I have tried to look for "next" or "enter" in the keycodes but nothing really relevant...
does anyone know?

(actually, i've found the enter keycode to be precise, but it does not do anything)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `setOnEditorActionListener()` on the `EditText`, and give that `EditText` a suitable `android:imeActionId` value and a suitable `android:imeOptions` value (e.g., `"actionSearch"`). The listener you provide to `setOnEditorActionListener()` will be notified when the user taps that button.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction.
I just added one line to my code, and it did it perfectly :
myEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);